# How to get complete URL of iframe website

Tags: php, iframe, geturl

My website is an iframe base website. it has following link,

```
localhost/folder/index.php/#!/post/
```

I can't figure out how to grab the `"/#!/post/"` part of the URL.

I am using the following php script to get url but its only get url till "index.php".

```
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

Can anybody help me to get complete URL through PHP??? , I am new in development so not much know about the technicalities.

Comment: http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs is a worthwhile read. Don't use hashbangs, use the history api instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hash fragments are not passed to the server; they are clientside-only. Since PHP is a serverside language, it will never be aware of them.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP will not use '#' (Fragment identifier), If you need the fragment identifier then get through the javascript like below

```
document.URL
```

If required send to PHP by posting through AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Javascript for this. The segment after the # is not sent to server, so PHP can't retrieve that part.

In javascript you can use `window.location` while will give you `localhost/folder/index.php/#!/post/`

To get the hashed part only, you can use `window.location.hash` which will give you `#!/post/`.